# Scanf skipping character in c

Tags: c, scanf

```
int main(){
    int firstNumber, secondNumber, thirdNumber;
    char oper;

    scanf("%d", &firstNumber);
    printf("%d\n", firstNumber);

    scanf("%c", &oper);
    printf("%c\n", oper);

    scanf("%d", &secondNumber);
    printf("%d\n", secondNumber);


    return 0;
}
```

Why this code doesn't work as expected, It reads the first and the second number but it doesn't read the character in between.

Comment: Read [documentation of `scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). You should test its return count. Read also [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Define "something weird".

Comment: by weird i mean it doesn't read it, just kinda skips it i think

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scanf() leaves the new line char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `scanf()` is hard. Here, there is a newline character left on `stdin` from you hitting enter after the first number. So, that's the character you read. Some format conversions ignore whitespace, but `%c` does not.

To make it ignore leading whitespace, you should instead use

```
scanf(" %c", &oper);
```

The space in the format string tells `scanf()` to ignore any whitespaces it finds, so you will read a non-whitespace character.